# Nested resource failing to update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to do what I think should be simple: do a simple edit on a single text string field with the default update action. But it just doesn't seem to work, despite many attempts and alterations.

There are no errors and the flash message responds successfully, but information isn't saved to the database at all:

routes.rb

```
resources :interviews do
  resources :invitations do
    put :accept
  end
end
```

views/invitations/edit.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for [@interview, @invitation] do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :testing
  = f.submit 'Edit Invitstion', :class => 'button small'
```

controllers/invitations_controller.rb

```
def update
  @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
  @interview = Interview.find(params[:interview_id])

  @invitation.update_attributes(invitation_params)

  if @invitation.update_attributes(invitation_params)
    redirect_to edit_interview_invitation_path(@interview, @invitation), notice:  "Your profile has been successfully updated."
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end

private

def invitation_params
  params.permit(:user_id, :interview_id, :invitation_id, :session_time, :workflow_state, :testing)
end
```

And here's the log:

```
Started PATCH "/interviews/3/invitations/7" for ::1 at 2016-05-15 19:01:52 +0800
Processing by InvitationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"o0U5t0yPN0aE2er+DWK0uxqRGyp4ywfdSrEfvwiSQ3UUaOnr3Fd0raFs1IUqVzizKoqxRU0DDpmvysntB9fdhQ==", "invitation"=>{"interview_id"=>"3", "workflow_state"=>"invited", "session_time"=>"", "testing"=>"testtesttest"}, "commit"=>"Edit Invitstion", "interview_id"=>"3", "id"=>"7"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  Invitation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Interview Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "interviews".* FROM "interviews" WHERE "interviews"."id" = $1  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "7"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "interviews".* FROM "interviews" WHERE "interviews"."id" = $1  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, invitation, commit, id
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Invitation Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "invitations" WHERE ("invitations"."user_id" = 3 AND "invitations"."id" != 7 AND "invitations"."interview_id" = 3) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/interviews/3/invitations/7/edit
Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)


Started GET "/interviews/3/invitations/7/edit" for ::1 at 2016-05-15 19:01:52 +0800
Processing by InvitationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"interview_id"=>"3", "id"=>"7"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  Invitation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Interview Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "interviews".* FROM "interviews" WHERE "interviews"."id" = $1  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered invitations/edit.html.haml within layouts/application (6.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 39.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are calling  @invitation.update_attributes(invitation_params) twice?

Comment: @Bustikiller I was just hacking to try and see if something related to that might have been causing the problem. Anthony's solution was the right one though, so I've cleaned up all this other junk too now :)

Comment: Perfect! Just wanted to make sure you hadn't missed that detail ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the format of your params object in your logs. Your invitation params are being passed within the `params["invitation"]` key, yet you're whitelisting and updating your object based on the params in the root params hash.

Also note that your logs are reporting that you're trying to update your invitation with unpermitted params:

> Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, invitation, commit, id

You can fix this by simply updating your `invitation_params` to use `params[:invitation]` rather than `params` like so:

```
def invitation_params
  params.require(:invitation).permit(:user_id, :interview_id, :invitation_id, :session_time, :workflow_state, :testing)
end
```

Also, you might want to consider raising an error if you're trying to update a parameter that's not whitelisted to  prevent these sorts of issues in the future.

In your rails config:

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

Comment: Ridiculous. I spent about 5 hours hacking away on this trying different things and I'd seen that `.require(:invitation)` part in loads of places, but didn't realise it was significant. Fixed things immediately--thanks so much!

Comment: Yup, I've been burned by that several times too. I find it's always best to set `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise` just for good measure.